# Getting column from a multidimensional list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a quite involved nested list: each element is a tuple with two elements: one is an object, the other is an 3x2xn array. Here is a toy model.

```
toy=[('mol1',array([[[1,1,1],[2,2,2]],[[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]])),('mol2',array([[[1,1,1],[2,2,2]],[[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]]))]
```

How can I get a single column from that?

I am looking for

```
('mol1', 'mol2')
```

and for the 2Darrays like:

```
array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
```

I have a solution but I think it is pretty inefficient:

```
zip(*toy)[0]
```

it returns

```
('mol1', 'mol2')
```

then

```
zip(*toy)[1][0][:,0]
```

which returns

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]])
```

a for cycle like that

```
for i in range(len(toy)):
    zip(*toy)[1][i][:,0]
```

gives all the element of the column and I can build it with a vstack

Comment: Can you please clarify the *final* wanted output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be reasonably efficient:

```
>>> tuple(t[0] for t in toy)
('mol1', 'mol2')
```

For the 2D array, with the help of numpy's vstack function:

```
>>> from numpy import vstack
>>> vstack([t[1][:, 0] for t in toy])
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array in numpy to store your data or convert yours to that, then use the column slicing function built in. In general numpy slicing is very fast.

```
import numpy as np
np.asarray(toy)[::, 0] # first column

# output
array(['mol1', 'mol2'], 
      dtype='|S4')
```